# This member is defined more than once error with variable in if statement

Tags: c#, .net

The first button 2 and 1 get this error in the first and second if statements.
How can I get them to work?
Thanks in advance.

```
    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (button2 == true)
        {
            richTextBox1.AppendText(String.Format("Please continue with the midpoint.\n"));

        }
        else if(button2 == false)
        {
            richTextBox1.AppendText(String.Format("Type the first set of coordinates in.\n"));
            bool button1 = true;
        }


    }

    private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
          if (button1 == true)
        {
            richTextBox1.AppendText(String.Format("Please continue with the distance.\n"));

        }
        else if(button1== false)
        {
            richTextBox1.AppendText(String.Format("Type the first set of coordinates in.\n"));
            bool button2 = true;
        }

    }
}
```

}

Comment: you are mixing variable declaration and value assignment

Comment: button1 is already the name of the button, so you can't create a variable named that. Same with button2.

Comment: You can define local variables with the same name as members, you'll get a warning, but not a compiler error.

Comment: Can you post the *real* code? If `button1` or `button2` are bool types, why do you have click events? I suspect you simplified it too much and thus mangled the code.

Answer (score 1):

```
bool button1 = true;
```

I assume you already have a bool value defined somewhere looking at your sample, in which case you do not need to specify the type again:

```
button1 = true
```

Comment: I get the same errror with this.

Comment: @Max, you cannot get *the same* error if you make the change shown. You may get another error, in which case share it with us.

Comment: @DavidArno I'm guessing the error is something like "no implicit conversion exists to convert bool to System.Windows.Forms.Button" or something like that.

Answer (score 1):

You need to define these members at class level as `private` member may be as well as give them a different name/identifier since `button1` and `button2` most probably be your `button` control name.

```
public class someclass
{
private bool mbutton2 = false;
private bool mbutton1 = false;

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (mbutton2)
        {
            richTextBox1.AppendText(String.Format
                      ("Please continue with the midpoint.\n"));
        }
        else
        {
            richTextBox1.AppendText(String.Format
                  ("Type the first set of coordinates in.\n"));
            mbutton1 = true;
        }
    }

    private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
          if (mbutton1)
        {
            richTextBox1.AppendText(String.Format
                    ("Please continue with the distance.\n"));

        }
        else
        {
            richTextBox1.AppendText(String.Format
                  ("Type the first set of coordinates in.\n"));
            mbutton2 = true;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This will still give an error, he already has something else named `button1` and `button2`. The names need to be different. See the declaration of the event handlers, the buttons themselves are named that already.

Comment: @RonBeyer, answer goes with assumption that `button1` or `button2` are not his button control name. If they are then his posted code actually doesn't make sense since a `button` control can't be assigned `bool` value.

Comment: Thats why he's getting the error that its already defined (in the title of the question).